# How to access Page layouts and site templates using CSOM?

Tags: client-object-model

How to access Site Settings > Look and Feel > Page layouts and site templates using CSOM?

The page allows end users to change these settings:

- Subsite Templates: subsites can use any site template or following site templates: ...
- Page Layouts: Pages can use any layout or following layouts: ...
- New Page Default Settings (inherit default page or select)
- Reset all subsites to inherit these new page settings

Comment: Did you achieve this using PowerShell?